# Generate 9 million unique random numeric only string

Tags: java, random, uniqueidentifier, unique-id

Queustion 1: Can we generate 8 digit unique 9-10 million numeric only strings?

Queustion 2: How do I generate 9 to 10 million unique 'numeric only' string in one program run? These keys will be uploaded to db to be used for next 6 months. I tried

```
Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000000) + 10000000;
```

in a loop, but produces lots of duplicates. To eliminate duplicates, I used HashSet, but I get Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space after ~140xxxx size in the set. Any other approach to generate this output?

Comment: your general approach can be wrong. why can't you try sequences in db?

Comment: why not a few more digits, then you can use UUID? Much less hassle.

Comment: @arghtype: Frequently that's a useful way to go, but sometimes it's important that people receiving these numbers (perhaps they're IDs of some kind) shouldn't be able to predict or infer anything from them. For instance, if I get 12345678 and you get 23456789, in some situations it's best if I not be able to infer that you got your number after I got mine. So randomness *can* have a place, provided there's a genuine use case for it.

Comment: I cant use the db sequence, because these numbers are the coupon code sent out to the customer for the next 6 months. So as Crowder said it should be unpredictable.

Comment: I posted my answer to this question, but forgot to tick the appropriate answers here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is one time run just increase the heap by using command line option `-Xmx2048M` (2G is just and example).

Answer (score 4):

The standard approach to creating a block of unique random numbers is to first create the numbers in order (for instance, in an array), then shuffle them.

You need to be careful in your choice of shuffling algorithms; I hear [Fisher-Yates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher-Yates_shuffle) is pretty good.

Answer (score 1):

**Q1. Can we generate 8 digit unique 9-10 million numeric only strings?**

yes you can generate 10000000 8 digit unique numeric only strings using 10 digits 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0

If you are writing correct logic for all possible combination you will not get any duplicate but just to be in safe side you can use set.

As you are getting java.lang.OutOfMemoryError error that's because you are generating that many numbers and keeping it in memory. solution for this is you generate some small chunk of numbers and save it into the database and then clear the list and again fill with the next chunk of numbers and keep it repeating untill you saved all the numbers into the database.

**Q2. How do I generate 9 to 10 million unique 'numeric only' string in one program run?**

here is a combination code you can use it to achieve your goal

```
public class Combination{
    public static int count = 0;
    public static ArrayList<String> list;

    public Combination(){
        list = new ArrayList<String>();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Combination c = new Combination();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String str = sc.next();
        int num = sc.nextInt();
        if(num>str.length()){
            System.out.println("This combination is not possible");
            System.out.println(num+" should be less than or equal to the length of the string "+str);
        }else{
            System.out.println("Processing....");
            char[] array = new char[num];
            c.fillNthCharacter(0,array,str);
            System.out.println("Total combination = "+count);
        }
    }

    public static void fillNthCharacter(int n,char[] array,String str){
        for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++){
            array[n]=str.charAt(i);
            if(n<array.length-1){
                fillNthCharacter(n+1,array,str);
            }else{
                count++;
                //System.out.println(new String(array));
                list.add(new String(array));
                if(list.size()>100000){
                    //code to add into database
                    list.clear();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I simply increased the vm memory size and ran the application to generate 9 million coupons. Thank you everyone for taking interest in answering this.

Answer (score 0):

You can store them in a database and put an index on the column where you store them (with obiouvsly a unique constraint and a loop to retry if a DuplicateKeyException occurs). Even better, you can write a stored procedure to do it and operate directly on the database. I use this approach when generating short codes for urls (that can lead to duplicates). If your time requirements are not stringent, this is a viable option.